# Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that $f'(c) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I would like some help on this problem I've been struggling to solve for a while.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,+\infty)$ and differentiable on $(0,+\infty)$ such that $\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = f(0)$.
Prove that there exists $c>0$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

So this actually reminds me of Rolle's theorem but I can't use it since it has to be used on a closed interval. My intuition is that $f$ should be bounded and thus it changes its monotonicity which makes its derivative equal to 0 at a certain point.

The problem is no matter how I tried I wasn't able to write a full rigorous proof so if you could help me on that I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually *can* use Rolle’s theorem.

Consider the function

$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
  f(\tan(x)) & x \in [0, \pi / 2)\\
  f(0) & x = \pi / 2
\end{cases}$$

Then $g$ is continuous on $[0, \pi/2]$ and differentiable on $(0, \pi/2)$. Moreover, $g(0) = g(\pi/2)$. By Rolle’s theorem, there is some $k \in (0, \pi/2)$ with $g’(k) = 0$. By the chain rule, $g’(k) = \sec^2(k) f’(\tan(k)) = 0$. Thus, $f’(\tan(k)) = 0$. Let $c = \tan(k)$.

Comment: Nice (+). The substitution $f(x/(1-x))$ for $[0,1)$ works as well.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, all we need is a continuous bijection $[0, c) \to [0, \infty)$ with positive derivative on $(0, c)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is constant, then we are done. If $f$ is not constant, our hypothesis $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x) = f(0)$ implies $f$ is not monotonic, that is, $f$ is not injective, so that there are real numbers $a\neq b$ with $f(a) = f(b)$. Applying Rolle's Theorem completes the proof.